# How to get the published date of page displayed on Page Template using VB Script Templating

Tags: 2011, vbscript

We have a offer xml which is published and we want to read the last published date of that offers xml page to be displayed on (offers asp page) where we display all the offers at the page template level.

Tridion Version : Tridion 2011 SP1
Templating : VB Script [Legecy]

Comment: I'll let others offer a technical answer, but I typically [recommend _against_ using the published date directly](http://www.createandbreak.net/2013/08/use-these-automation-options-sparingly.html). Especially with DTAP and content updates, the business often wants to control what date displays independent of when it's published to do things like "back dating" an rendered item.

Comment: I would like to give you a heads up that after 30 June 2016 SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 will become fully retired, and no further service packs or
hotfixes will be available. Also the VBscript Templating model has been deprecated and you really should consider upgrading to a different templating model. This certainly makes sense when you are looking at developing new feature for existing templates. You don't want to invest time in new features on a deprecated model.

Comment: bart Yes we are going to upgrade soon

Answer (score 2):

In VbScript, the `Now()` function will get you the current Date/Time. There are various other functions you can use to format or manipulate it. You can easily Google to find out about these.

You could use this to output the publish date in the XML. In the page template that renders offers.asp you could output ASP code that reads the XML and extracts the date.